# Why is first itteration skipped in setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run the below function:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import classes from '../Main.module.css';

export default function Intro() {
  // Timing Settings (for convenience)
    const highlightInterval = 50;
    const typingInterval = 75;
    const delayInterval = 1000;
  // ---------------------------------

  const greeterMsgE = 'Hello, it\'s nice to meet you...';
  const greeterMsgC = '你好, 很高兴认识你...';

  function makeSpanSequence(msg) {
    const _ = msg.split('');
    return _.map((char, i = 0) => (<span key={i}>{char}</span>))
  }

  const [currentGreetMsg, setCurrentGreetMsg] = useState(makeSpanSequence(greeterMsgC))
  const [typerEngaged, setTyperEngaged] = useState(false)

  function greeterTyper() {
    function highlighter() {
      let index = currentGreetMsg.length
      const highTime = setInterval(() => {
        if (index <= 0) {
          clearInterval(highTime)
          setTimeout(clearGreeting, delayInterval);
        } else {
          setCurrentGreetMsg(prev => {
            prev.splice(index, 1, (<span key={index} className={classes.typerH}>{currentGreetMsg[index].props.children}</span>))
            return [...prev]
          })
          index--
        }
      }, highlightInterval);
    }

    function clearGreeting() {
      setCurrentGreetMsg([(<br key={'br'} />)])
      setTimeout(typeNew, delayInterval)
    }

    function typeNew() {
      const newMessage = makeSpanSequence(greeterMsgE);
      let index = 0;
      setCurrentGreetMsg([newMessage[0]])
      const typeTime = setInterval(() => {
        if (index >= newMessage.length){
          clearInterval(typeTime)
        } else {
          setCurrentGreetMsg(prev => {
            const _ = [...prev, newMessage[index]]
            return _
          })
          index++
        }
      }, typingInterval);
    }

    setTimeout(highlighter, 1500);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (typerEngaged ? greeterTyper() : setTyperEngaged(true))
  }, [typerEngaged])


  return (
    <>
    <h2 className={classes.typerGreeting}>{currentGreetMsg}</h2>

    <p>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    
    <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <button>More...</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

It types out the message as expected, but it seems to skip the first letter every time. I could set 'index' to -1 which fixes the immediate problem, but I am still unsure why it skipping 'setCurrentGreetMsg' on the first go.

As far as I can tell, it literally skips it the first time, increments 'index' by one, then every subsequent time executes 'setCurrentGreetMsg' and then increments 'index' by one as expected.

Comment: What is your `newMessage`? Can you post full code?

Comment: I edited the post to show the entire component. @Enfieldli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the value of `index` in the callback of `setCurrentGreetMsg`. The callback does not necessarily execute immediately. By the time the callback function get executed, the `index--` had already been executed.

You can take a look at this example to get the concept.
`0` never get printed because `index++` has been executed before `foo` execute `callback`.

```js
var index = 0;

function foo(callback)
{
  setTimeout(callback,500);
}

setInterval(()=>{
  foo(()=>{
    console.log(index)
  });
  console.log(`increment index from ${index++} to ${index}`);
},1000);
```

To get around this problem, store the value intended to be used locally, instead of using the global variable itself.

```js
var index = 0;

function foo(callback)
{
  setTimeout(callback,500);
}

setInterval(()=>{
  const tmp = index;
  foo(()=>{
    console.log(tmp)
  });
  console.log(`increment index from ${index++} to ${index}`);
},1000);
```

Comment: ah this makes sense. Would you have a recommendation to get around this issue? or is starting the index at -1 sufficient in your expertise? (also thank you so much for clearing that up)

Comment: Simply store the value of `index` intended to be used, instead of using `index` itself. `const tmp = index;  setCurrentGreetMsg(/*use tmp*/); index--;`